# Solution not calculating number of letters in answer for 17

Tags: dart

I produced a program to solve problem 17

```dart
Number letter counts
Problem 17
If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?


NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.
```

My attempt, in dart, minus the main method, as shown below

```dart
isSpecialBelow100(number) {
  switch(number) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
      case 10:
      case 11:
      case 12:
      case 13:
      case 14:
      case 15:
      case 16:
      case 17:
      case 18:
      case 19:
      case 20:
      case 30:
      case 40:
      case 50:
      case 60:
      case 70:
      case 80:
      case 90:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
  }
}


removeExcess(number, weight) => number - number % weight;

getExcess(number, weight) => number % weight;

specialNumberToWord(number) {
  switch(number) {
    case 1:
      return 'one';
    case 2:
      return 'two';
    case 3:
      return 'three';
    case 4:
      return 'four';
    case 5:
      return 'five';
    case 6:
      return 'six';
    case 7:
      return 'seven';
    case 8:
      return 'eight';
    case 9:
      return 'nine';
    case 10:
      return 'ten';
    case 11:
      return 'eleven';
    case 12:
      return 'twelve';
    case 13:
      return 'thirteen';
    case 14:
      return 'forteen';
    case 15:
      return 'fifteen';
    case 16:
      return 'sixteen';
    case 17:
      return 'seventeen';
    case 18:
      return 'eighteen';
    case 19:
      return 'nineteen';
    case 20:
      return 'twenty';
    case 30:
      return 'thirty';
    case 40:
      return 'forty';
    case 50:
      return 'fifty';
    case 60:
      return 'sixty';
    case 70:
      return 'seventy';
    case 80:
      return 'eighty';
    case 90:
      return 'ninety';
    default:
      return '';
  }
}


printProblem17Result() {
  var words = new StringBuffer();
  for(var number = 1; number <= 1000; number++) {
    if(number < 100) {
      if(isSpecialBelow100(number)) {
        words.write(specialNumberToWord(number));
      } else {
        words.write(specialNumberToWord(removeExcess(number, 10)));
        words.write(' ');
        words.write(specialNumberToWord(getExcess(number, 10)));
      }
    } else if(number >= 100 && number < 1000) {
      var remaining = int.parse(removeExcess(number, 100).toString().replaceAll('0', ''));
      words.write(specialNumberToWord(remaining));
      words.write(' hundred ');
      var excess = getExcess(number, 100);
      if(excess != 0) {
        words.write(' and ');
        if(isSpecialBelow100(excess)) {
          words.write(specialNumberToWord(excess));
        } else {
          words.write(specialNumberToWord(removeExcess(excess, 10)));
          words.write(' ');
          words.write(specialNumberToWord(getExcess(excess, 10)));
        }
      }
    } else {
      words.write(' one thousand');
    }
    words.write(' ');
  }

  print(words.toString().split(' ').fold(0, (prev, current) => prev + current.length));
}
```

While maybe not the tidiest as far as I can see should produce the right number of characters.

It seems to fall short of the solution by 10.  Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

UPDATE:

I didn't add in the spelling correction, but I did remove the newline character and replaced it with a space, and corrected the split method to split on spaces.  The version I had originally posted was an attempt at debugging, via the much maligned print line method.

Indeed the correct spelling of 14 is fourteen, not forteen, which is easy to overlook at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake for 14 should be fourteen not 'forteen'.

Also you seem to be counting the new line character correct with

```
  print( (words.toString().replaceAll(' ','').replaceAll('\n','')).length);
```

Correct this and you should get the answer 21124.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple like that, thanks.  Newline wasn't supposed to be there, thanks for spotting that, that was part of my attempt ot make sense of the output, by outputting each number on it's own line, etc.